# Python list comprehension for if and elif function

Tags: python

```
from datetime import date

a_dictionary = {"name" : "John", "age" : 35, "height" : 65}

dict_items = a_dictionary.items()


def month_selct(d):
    if date.today().month == 1:
        d = list(d)[:2]

    elif date.today().month == 2:
        d = list(d)[:2]

    elif date.today().month == 3:
        d = list(d)[:2]

month_selct(dict_items)
```

Can you help me with reduction this code? I want this function work with each month but its just an example for 3 of it

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to do. Each part of your `if`/`elif` ladder does exactly the same thing, and since nothing is returned or output there is no effect in the end.

Comment: you will need to provide a [mre]

Comment: a_dictionary and d = list(d)[:2] is just an example, this could be anything else. I need reduction for code on each month

Comment: from the information given use either a list or a dictionary, you will need to provide more details and/or examples, specific examples for us to help you better

Comment: lets imagine that a_dictionary have 12 items. I want 1 item for month == 1, 2 items for month == 2, 3 items for month == 3 and so on with shorter version than my

Comment: if you're adding information don't comment, edit your question

Comment: IIUC you actually want this: `return list(d)[:date.today().month]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a switch logic in python with a dictionary:

```
def month_selct(d):
    switch = {
        1 : list(d)[:2],
        2 : list(d)[:2],
        3 : list(d)[:2],
        11: list(d)[:2]
    }
    return switch[date.today().month]

print(month_selct(dict_items))
```

Comment: he said `for each month` you don't need the function at all

Comment: @diggusbickus this is an example, they didn't need to provide every single case, they have done a great job at showing the general way (except maybe the switch could be a global constant and not defined in the function as to not create that dictionary each time the function is called (tho then those should be `lambda`s and it's not that big of an issue if the function is not called often)), functions however are pretty handy so it kinda needs to be in a function, it is rarely the case that something like this would be used only once so the function avoids completely unnecessary repetition

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? He wants a function so why would you get rid of the function? Of course my example should be filled with all twelve month but so is OP's example in the question.

Comment: Also I guess OP will want to fill their dictionary with something else than `list(d)[:2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate through each month and check if that's the month you're in, as follows:

```
def month_select(d):
    for m in range(1, 13):
        if date.today().month == m:
            d = list(d)[:2]
```

EDIT: you asked for a list comprehension solution

```
d = [list(d)[:2] for m in range(1, 13) if date.today().month == m]
```

Comment: exactly what does this achieve? the `if` will always be True at some point, so how do you plan to differ whether it is m or m?

Comment: To me it sounded like OP is trying to execute code depending on the current month. Just like OP's solution, true, this will always be True at some point, which is what they want, but just with less code, which is what this does.

Comment: in the given case it will always run the `if` block, might as well just then do only `d = list(d)[:2]`, there is no reason to have it set up like this, there has to be another condition or something

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but atm OP is doing the same thing for each case (which is indeed questionable) so *shrug shoulders*